# I can't iterate on the template

Tags: django, forms, loops

I have a mutable dictionary with all my forms and i want to iterate on the template show all the forms that i have on my dictionary without hardcoding them like {{ example_form }}
this is my code

```
{% extends 'prescription_menu.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Physicians{% endblock title %}

{% block container %}
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        {% for form in forms %}
            {{form}}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock container %}
```

And this is my view

```
def UpdatePhysician(request,id):

forms = {}
physician = get_object_or_404(Physician, id=id)
employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=physician.employee.id)
person = get_object_or_404(Person, id=employee.person.id)
try:
    address = get_object_or_404(Address, id=return_id(str(person.addresses.values('id'))))
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST or None, instance=address)
    forms.update({'address_form': address_form})
except:
    address = None
email = get_object_or_404(Email, id=return_id(str(person.emails.values('id'))))
phone = get_object_or_404(PhoneNumber, id=return_id(str(person.phone_numbers.values('id'))))

person_form = PersonForm(request.POST or None, instance=person)
employee_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, instance=employee)
physician_form = PhysicianForm(request.POST or None, instance=physician)
email_form = EmailForm(request.POST or None, instance=email)
phone_form = PhoneForm(request.POST or None, instance=phone)

forms.update({'person_form': person_form,
              'physician_form': physician_form,
              'employee_form': employee_form,
              'email_form': email_form,
              'phone_form': phone_form,
              })



return render(request, 'UpdatePhysician.html',forms)
```

It doesn't throw me any error, it just don't show anything, and when I type `{{person_form}}` for example, I get the form that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `forms` variable is a `dict`. Therefore you have to loop through a dicht in the template:

```
{% for name, form in forms.items %}
   {{form}}
{%endfor%}
```

And in the view you have to change the last line to

```
return render(request, 'UpdatePhysician.html', {'forms': forms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your forms to a list:

```
form_list = [person_form, physician_form, employee_form, email_form, phone_form]
```

And the add this to your context dictionary, in this case, your `forms` dictionary is the `context` dictionary:

```
forms.update({'forms': form_list})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{form}}
{% endfor %}
```